# SQL: Error invalid filegroup specified

Tags: sql-server

When I try to create a table:

```
USE [myDB];
CREATE TABLE [myTable] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DataFS] [varbinary](max),
    [MimeType] [nvarchar](100),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.myTable] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
) on NewFileStream
```

I get an error.

> Invalid filegroup 'NewFileStream' specified.

However, I can see the filegroup NewFileStream in the list:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    sys.filegroups
```

Comment: Do you use the - sa - user to create the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filegroup name `NewFileStream` suggests it is a filestream filegroup. You cannot place table rows on a filestream file group. To create a table with a filestream column, you need to:

- specify a file group defined for rows data
- specify a file group defined for file stream data
- specify ROWGUIDCOL and a unique constraint on the uniqueidentifier column
- specify FILESTREAM for the filestream column

The example places rows on the default filegroup and the filegroup column on NewFileStream.

```
CREATE TABLE [myTable] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL CONSTRAINT UQ_myTable_Guid UNIQUE,
    [DataFS] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM,
    [MimeType] [nvarchar](100),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.myTable] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
) ON [DEFAULT] FILESTREAM_ON NewFileStream;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for answer Dan

Answer (score 0):

in ssms, first you can create database from menu by right click on databases and set filegroup same there or if DB is created, before creating any table right click on your DB name and in properties select filegroup page from the left and setting up it.